# Why can I assign an int to a Short for return type but not in parameter list?

Tags: java

This code will not compile:

```
class App {
    Short foo() {
        return 3;
    }

    void bar(Short s){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App().foo();
        new App().bar(3);
    }
}
```

with the message:

```
App.java:12: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Short
new App().bar(3);
```

How come the compiler has no issues returning `3` in `foo` which has return type `Short` but will not accept `3` for the `Short` in the parameter list?

Comment: Try using a literal that doesn't fit into the range for short. Also try what happens when you try to return an int variable...

Comment: I think his point is that he *\*is\** using a literal, and that the literal is in the range for a Short.  I'm kinda confused how this works too.

Comment: I think that in `return 3;` you actually create a short literal without needing any casting.

Comment: Yes, that's what's happening, but why doesn't it also happen in the other case?

Comment: Well I was wrong (see the accepted answer), but if I if I delete my comment the last comment won't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found myself chasing my own tail on this question, until I read the JLS and basically just concluded that the answer is, because the creators of Java made it this way.

Regarding why `new App().bar(3)` fails, the JLS has one rule for method invocations using boxing:

> [5.3. Method Invocation Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3)
>   a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by widening reference conversion

A reference conversion in this context means:

> A widening reference conversion exists from any reference type S to any reference type T, provided S is a subtype (§4.10) of T.

So, the compiler will go so far as to try:

```
new App().bar(new Integer(3))
```

But since `Short` and `Integer` are not subclass of each other (they are in fact both subclasses of `Number`), a widening reference conversion is not possible.  So this method call fails with the compiler error you were seeing.

As for why the following is allowed:

```
Short foo() {
    return 3;
}
```

we can also look to the JLS' discussion of assignment conversion.  Buried in there we find the following:

> [5.2. Assignment Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)
>   A narrowing primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion may be used if the type of the variable is:

- Byte and the value of the constant expression is representable in the
  type byte.
- Short and the value of the constant expression is representable in
  the type short.
- Character and the value of the constant expression is representable
  in the type char.

So the compiler can handle the `foo()` method as:

```
Short foo() {
    return Short.valueOf(3);
}
```